# warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]

Tags: c

I get the warning "warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]" and also when I run the program it wont read any input I give it. I've been spending hours figuring out ways to make this program work due to being new with programming. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
int oilChange = 35;
int tireRotation = 19;
int carWash = 7;
int carWax = 12;
int totPrice = 0;
char service1[15];
char service2[15];

printf("Davy's auto shop services\n");                                  //printing the menu
printf("Oil change -- $%d\n", oilChange);
printf("Tire rotation -- $%d\n", tireRotation);
printf("Car wash -- $%d\n", carWash);
printf("Car wax -- $%d\n\n", carWax);

printf("Select first service: ");                                      //prompting and reading first service
scanf("%[^\n]%s", service1);
printf("%s", service1);

printf("Select second service: ");                                     //prompting and reading service service
scanf("%[^\n]%s", service1);
printf("%s", service2);
```

Comment: First of all, your use of scanf() is unsafe, e.g. if more than 14 characters are entered. Lookup "Buffer Overflow" for more. It is a common security vulnerability.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the full error message, and indicate which line this error occurred on. The code looks OK as is, so we need more information.

Answer (score 4):

The input format:

```
scanf("%[^\n]%s", service1);
```

has two conversion specifications — the scan set and the string.  You've only provided one variable.  That's why you're getting the compiler warning.  You probably want something like:

```
scanf("%s", service1);
```

The string conversion will skip white space, including newlines, and read a single word into `service1`.

Or it's possible you want:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", service1);
```

That also skips white space, then reads the rest of a line into `service1`.

All `scanf()` conversion specifiers except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` skip white space automatically.

You should also [prevent buffer overflow with `scanf()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1621973/15168) by using `"%14s"` or `" %14[^\n]"`.

Note that you prompt for "Select second service" but read the value into `service1` again (not `service2`).  You then print the value from `service2`.  You should change the `1` to `2` in the `scanf()` line, as well as fixing the format string.